# How to activate all skin buttons and keys in android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

There are some problems with my android emulator:

1. Home button doesn't work its looks like disable !!
2. There is no keyboard in the left side !!!
3. There is no menu !

How can I setup a new one with all features ?

Screen shot:

[image]

Comment: The screenshot you provide is from the boot sequence. Does your emulator finished loading?

Comment: Yes,and I've updated my post

Answer (score 1):

Edit the emulator and tick the box that says `Display a skin with hardware controls` and then restart the emulator.

It looks like you're using an old Android version, maybe Gingerbread which doesn't support soft keys which I think is why you are having issues.

Comment: I did this tick and nothing changed , Version: 3.7.2 :(

Comment: Oh odd, just as a test, it may be worth checking the box for using hardware keyboard as well and restart the emulator. Are there any errors in the logcat

Comment: No there are no errors :\ I don't know why my emulator don't have any feature ???!!